# Modify config file using bash script

Tags: bash, configuration-files

I'm writing a bash script to modify a config file which contains a bunch of key/value pairs. How can I read the key and find the value and possibly modify it?

Comment: I tried to answer this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47509618/3343801

Answer (score 120, accepted):

A wild stab in the dark for modifying a single value:

```
sed -c -i "s/\($TARGET_KEY *= *\).*/\1$REPLACEMENT_VALUE/" $CONFIG_FILE
```

assuming that the target key and replacement value don't contain any special regex characters, and that your key-value separator is "=". Note, the -c option is system dependent and you may need to omit it for sed to execute.

For other tips on how to do similar replacements (e.g., when the REPLACEMENT_VALUE has '/' characters in it), [there are some great examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5955591/564709).

Comment: -c seems to be invalid in my environment. When I get rid of -c, it works. Thanks.

Comment: The `-c` option tells sed to copy the file when it shuffles it (instead of renaming) - it prevents changing ownership and messing with read-only files. One of those habits I've picked up to save myself from stupid mistakes (especially with `find ... | xargs sed -i`).

Comment: Did I really get two downvotes for this answer? Not only did I manage to guess what the OP wanted, it's short and efficient. Anyone care to explain?

Comment: Any chance you can explain how to do this if i need to do this same thing, except i need to do it through ssh into a remote machine. If you know an alternative way to do the same thing, that would suffice as well. Thanks

Comment: @prolink: `ssh [opts] [user@]hostname command` will log in then run the given command. If the command is complex enough, you might want to store it in a script on the remote so you can just run `ssh <host> path/to/script`.

Comment: If anyone perform it on a Mac environment, you might want to remove -c and add '' after -i. just like `sed -i '' "s...." $CONFIG_FILE`

Comment: Very useful script. If all your keys start at the beginning of the lines, consider adding `^` before `$TARGET_KEY`, otherwise if you have two keys like `even=2` and `noteven=1` you'll end up changing both.

Comment: How about adding the value in case it doesn't exist previously?

Comment: Does not work with tabs, does not take slashes in $REPLACEMENT_VALUE

Answer (score 23):

Hope this helps someone. I created a self contained script, which required config processing of sorts.

```
#!/bin/bash
CONFIG="/tmp/test.cfg"

# Use this to set the new config value, needs 2 parameters. 
# You could check that $1 and $2 is set, but I am lazy
function set_config(){
    sudo sed -i "s/^\($1\s*=\s*\).*\$/\1$2/" $CONFIG
}

# INITIALIZE CONFIG IF IT'S MISSING
if [ ! -e "${CONFIG}" ] ; then
    # Set default variable value
    sudo touch $CONFIG
    echo "myname=\"Test\"" | sudo tee --append $CONFIG
fi

# LOAD THE CONFIG FILE
source $CONFIG

echo "${myname}" # SHOULD OUTPUT DEFAULT (test) ON FIRST RUN
myname="Erl"
echo "${myname}" # SHOULD OUTPUT Erl
set_config myname $myname # SETS THE NEW VALUE
```

Comment: I doubt if this works with TOML, or even YAML or JSON, as they have sections. It works fine for just key-value pairs though

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you have a file of `key=value` pairs, potentially with spaces around the `=`, you can delete, modify in-place or append key-value pairs at will using `awk` even if the keys or values contain special regex sequences:

```
# Using awk to delete, modify or append keys
# In case of an error the original configuration file is left intact
# Also leaves a timestamped backup copy (omit the cp -p if none is required)
CONFIG_FILE=file.conf
cp -p "$CONFIG_FILE" "$CONFIG_FILE.orig.`date \"+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S\"`" &&
awk -F '[ \t]*=[ \t]*' '$1=="keytodelete" { next } $1=="keytomodify" { print "keytomodify=newvalue" ; next } { print } END { print "keytoappend=value" }' "$CONFIG_FILE" >"$CONFIG_FILE~" &&
mv "$CONFIG_FILE~" "$CONFIG_FILE" ||
echo "an error has occurred (permissions? disk space?)"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sed "/^$old/s/\(.[^=]*\)\([ \t]*=[ \t]*\)\(.[^=]*\)/\1\2$replace/" configfile
```

Answer (score 3):

So I can not take any credit for this as it is a combination of stackoverflow answers and help from irc.freenode.net #bash channel but here are bash functions now to both set and read config file values:

```sh
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/2464883
# Usage: config_set filename key value
function config_set() {
  local file=$1
  local key=$2
  local val=${@:3}

  ensureConfigFileExists "${file}"

  # create key if not exists
  if ! grep -q "^${key}=" ${file}; then
    # insert a newline just in case the file does not end with one
    printf "\n${key}=" >> ${file}
  fi

  chc "$file" "$key" "$val"
}

function ensureConfigFileExists() {
  if [ ! -e "$1" ] ; then
    if [ -e "$1.example" ]; then
      cp "$1.example" "$1";
    else
      touch "$1"
    fi
  fi
}

# thanks to ixz in #bash on irc.freenode.net
function chc() { gawk -v OFS== -v FS== -e 'BEGIN { ARGC = 1 } $1 == ARGV[2] { print ARGV[4] ? ARGV[4] : $1, ARGV[3]; next } 1' "$@" <"$1" >"$1.1"; mv "$1"{.1,}; }

# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331965/312709
# Usage: local myvar="$(config_get myvar)"
function config_get() {
    val="$(config_read_file ${CONFIG_FILE} "${1}")";
    if [ "${val}" = "__UNDEFINED__" ]; then
        val="$(config_read_file ${CONFIG_FILE}.example "${1}")";
    fi
    printf -- "%s" "${val}";
}
function config_read_file() {
    (grep -E "^${2}=" -m 1 "${1}" 2>/dev/null || echo "VAR=__UNDEFINED__") | head -n 1 | cut -d '=' -f 2-;
}
```

at first I was using the accepted answer's sed solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2464883/2683059

however if the value has a / char it breaks

Answer (score 0):

in general it's easy to extract the info with grep and cut:

```
cat "$FILE" | grep "^${KEY}${DELIMITER}" | cut -f2- -d"$DELIMITER"
```

to update you could do something like this:

```
mv "$FILE" "$FILE.bak"
cat "$FILE.bak" | grep -v "^${KEY}${DELIMITER}" > "$FILE"
echo "${KEY}${DELIMITER}${NEWVALUE}" >> "$FILE"
```

this would not maintain the order of the key-value pairs obviously. add error checking to make sure you don't lose your data.

Comment: if you run out of disk space or if for whatever reason you cannot create `FILE` then your solution will leave `FILE` missing (one would have to manually rename `FILE.bak` back to `FILE` to recover.)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this:

```
new_port=$1
sed "s/^port=.*/port=$new_port/" "$CONFIG_FILE" > /yourPath/temp.x
mv /yourPath/temp.x "$CONFIG_FILE"
```

This will change `port=` to `port=8888` in your config file if you choose 8888 as $1 for example.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose your config file is in below format:

```
CONFIG_NUM=4
CONFIG_NUM2=5
CONFIG_DEBUG=n
```

In your bash script, you can use:

```
CONFIG_FILE=your_config_file
. $CONFIG_FILE

if [ $CONFIG_DEBUG == "y" ]; then
    ......
else
    ......
fi
```

`$CONFIG_NUM`, `$CONFIG_NUM2`, `$CONFIG_DEBUG` is what you need.

After your read the values, write it back will be easy:

```
echo "CONFIG_DEBUG=y" >> $CONFIG_FILE
```

Comment: That won't replace the value, just add it again at the bottom, it's completely dependent on the config file being a valid bash script, and... wow, what if there's something malicious in the config file?