# How do I use sed to change my configuration files, with flexible keys and values?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to search a configuration file for this expression: "central.database".
I then want to change the setting associated with "central.database" to "SQLTEST".

The layout of the config file would look like this initially:

```
central.database = SQLFIRSTTEST
```

This is what i want it to look like after the sed replacement:

```
central.database = SQLTEST
```

I am doing this in a bash script, any suggestions, recommendations or alternative solutions are welcome!

(Actually both `central.database` and `SQLTEST` come from bash variables here.)

---

My current code (third attempt):

```
sshRetValue=$(ssh -p "35903" -i $HOME/sshids/idrsa-1.old ${1} <<EOF
        sed -i "s/^\($CENTRAL_DB_NAME\s*=\s*\).*\$/\1$CENTRAL_DB_VALUE/" /home/testing.txt;
        echo $?
EOF
)
```

Error message:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
sed: -e expression #1, char 58: unknown option to `s'
-bash: line 3: EOF: command not found
```

Comment: This is tagged [tag:linux] but the answers are *mostly* portable to other platforms. *BSD (including MacOS) users want to use `sed -i ""` where Linux permits just `sed -i`. There will also be differences in details of `sed` syntax between platforms, but simple `s/foo/bar/` should be completely portable.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Here's an example expression:

```
sed -i 's/^\(central\.database\s*=\s*\).*$/\1SQLTEST/' file.cfg
```

If you want to match stuff with `/` in it, you can use another delimiter:

```
sed -i 's#^\(cent/ral\.data/base\s*=\s*\).*$#\1SQL/TEST#' file.cfg
```

Or with variable expansion:

```
VAL="SQLTEST"
sed -i "s/^\(central\.database\s*=\s*\).*\$/\1$VAL/" file.cfg
```

In your example:

```
sshRetValue=`sed -i "s/^\(\1$CENTRAL_DB_NAME\s*=\s*\).*\$/\1$CENTRAL_DB_VALUE/" /home/testing.txt`;
```

There's a \1 before $CENTRAL_DB_NAME that's invalid. Also, sed doesn't print it's return value. This is the preferred way to check return values:

```
sed -i "s/^\($CENTRAL_DB_NAME\s*=\s*\).*\$/\1$CENTRAL_DB_VALUE/" /home/testing.txt;
sed_return_value=$?
```

And ultimately piping to ssh (not tested):

```
sed_return_value=$(ssh server <<EOF
    sed -i "s/^\($CENTRAL_DB_NAME\s*=\s*\).*\$/\1$CENTRAL_DB_VALUE/" /home/testing.txt;
    echo $?
EOF
)
```

The -i is for replacing data in the input file. Otherwise sed writes to stdout.

Regular expressions are a field of their own. It would be impossible to explain them in depth in a stackoverflow answer, unless there is some specific function that's eluding you.

Comment: The OP's requirement was that _"... both `central.database` and `SQLTEST` come from bash variables"_.  For example, say `KEY=central.database` and `VALUE=SQLTEST`.  How would you handle adding the escaped dot `\.` to the bash variable `$KEY`? (Perhaps `${KEY//./\\.}` would work, but I haven't tested this. What about `AIRPORT=$'O\'Hare'`?)

Answer (score 120):

```
sed -i -e '/central\.database =/ s/= .*/= new_value/' /path/to/file
```

Explanation:

- `-i` tells sed to save the results to the input file. Without it sed will print the results to stdout.
- `/central\.database =/` matches lines that contain the string between slashes: `central.database =`. The `.` is escaped since it's a special character in regex.
- The `s/OLD/NEW/` part performs a **s**ubstitution. The OLD string is a regular expression to match and the `NEW` part is the string to substitute in.
- In regular expressions, `.*` means "match anything". So `= .*` matches an equal sign, space, and then anything else afterward.

Comment: The OP's requirement was that "... both `central.database` and `SQLTEST` come from bash variables".  For example, say `CENTRAL_DB_KEY=central.database` and `CENTRAL_DB_VALUE=SQLTEST`.  How would you handle adding the escaped dot `\.` to the first bash variable? (Perhaps `${CENTRAL_DB_KEY//./\\.}` would work, but I haven't tested this. What about `AIRPORT=$'O\'Hare'`?)

Comment: For anyone that wants to change a key's value under a specific section, for example: ```[sectionA] central.database = new_val```, you can use sed's range addresses to do so: ```sed -i -e '/\[sectionA\]/, /central\.database =/ s/= .*/= new_value/' /path/to/file```

Answer (score 10):

I know it is too late to add an answer to this question however, I thought to share my knowledge to you all. There is a very general approach which I have followed to solve a similar kind of problem. I have deleted the whole line which is matching the string and added the required values to that key. To your question here is the answer

```
replaceValue=SQLTEST
sed -i "/central.database =/d" /home/testing.txt
echo "central.database = $replaceValue"  >> /home/testing.txt
```

sed deletes the matching string line from the file and the immediate next line is inserting the required key and value to the file.

Comment: This is the best answer if you don't know the key already exists. I think the simplicity is nicer and you will have less escaping issues

Comment: Also, the last line will not work with sudo. `tee` could be used instead:



`echo "central.database = $replaceValue" | sudo tee -a /home/testing.txt`

Answer (score 5):

I like using `awk` for this, since it is quite easy to understand what it is doing and takes care very well of the separator (`=`) and also the fact that it must be done to an uncommented line:

```
awk -v var="my_var" -v new_val="NEW VALUE" \  # set the vars
    'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}                        # set separator to =
     match($1, "^\\s*" var "\\s*") {          # check if it matches
         $2=" " new_val                       # if so, replace the line
     }1' conf_file                            # print all lines
```

This uses [`match()`](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html) to check if the pattern occurs in any given line. If it does, it performs the replacement with the given value.

For example:

```
$ cat conf
hello
my_var= SOME VALUE
#my_var = ANOTHER VALUE
bye
```

Let's change the value in `my_var` to `NEW VALUE`:

```
$ awk -v var="my_var" -v new_val="NEW VALUE" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}match($1, "^\\s*" var "\\s*") {$2=" " new_val}1' conf
hello
my_var= NEW VALUE
#my_var = ANOTHER VALUE
bye
```

It is also possible to set the values in shell variables and then use them with `-v`:

```
$ var="my_var"
$ new_value="NEW VALUE"
$ awk -v var="$var" -v new_val="$new_value" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}match($1, "^\\s*" var "\\s*") {$2=" " new_val}1' conf
```

And you can of course put all of this within a shell function that you then call normally:

```
#!/bin/bash

replace () {
   file=$1
   var=$2
   new_value=$3
   awk -v var="$var" -v new_val="$new_value" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}match($1, "^\\s*" var "\\s*") {$2=" " new_val}1' "$file"
}

# Call the replace() function with the necessary parameters
replace "conf" "my_var" "NEW VALUE"
```

Upon execution, this returns

```
hello
my_var= NEW VALUE
#my_var = ANOTHER VALUE
bye
```

While you can also make the script receive the parameters in a way like: `./script.sh "conf_file" "var_to_replace" "NEW VALUE"` to then pass them to the function.

Comment: @ThomasWeller of course, see my updated answer with this approach as well.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, this matches the beginning only. i.e. `replace my_conf.txt "foo" 1` will the replace the value for anything starting with `foo`.

Comment: As @sfrank mentioned, it takes also parts of variable names, if you add a $ sign at the end of match($1, "^\\s*" var "\\s*$") then it works for me only for entire variable names. I added a | grep $var at the end, so the output is no the whole file, but just relevant line candidates.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace between 2 property files you can use this:

```
awk -F= 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2;next}$1 in A{$2=A[$1]}1' OFS='\=' /tmp/masterfile /opt/props/finalfile.properties > /tmp/tmp.txt && mv -f /tmp/tmp.txt /opt/props/finalfile.properties
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a file called "config.php" and I wanted to change one of its definitions lines.

For example, the line:

```
define('SOME_CONSTANT', 'old_value');
```

had to be replaced with this one:

```
define('SOME_CONSTANT', 'new_value');
```

So I did that:

```
sed -i -e "/.*SOME_CONSTANT*./ s/.*/define('SOME_CONSTANT', 'new_value');/" path/to/config.php
```

In the first part, I am looking for a line that contains "SOME_CONSTANT" (thus the wildcards)

Then I replace that line with a new definition such as: define('SOME_CONSTANT', 'new_value');

Tested and works fine in Centos 7

Answer (score 1):

### Worked example

Imagine we want to update a Postgres configuration file to increase the number of connections.

We want to update this line in `/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf`:

```
max_connections = 100
```

Using sed:

```
sed -i 's/max_connections = 100/max_connections = 250/g' /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
```

This is rather useful when updating Docker configuration files as any updates require automating.

Answer (score 0):

I used this script for keeping the priorities..

The arguments
  $1 will have folder in which multiple config files exist. 
  $2 will have properties which need to be replaced in $1 path and sub paths files
  #3 will have properties which need to be override on top of $2

It also has hidden logic to check for existence of environment variables for the keys exist in $2 and $3 and give priority to that.

i.e If a key exist in environment that would be highest priority. Next to that would $3 and next to that would $1 file.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Usage is propertyReplacer <CONFIG_FOLDER_PATH> <CONFIG_FILE_2ND_PRIORITY> <CONFIG_FILE_1ST_PRIORITY>
function propertyReplacer() {

  filePathToAct="$1"
  propertiesFilePath="$2"
  propertiesSecureFilePath="$3"

  declare -A keyValues

  while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
    if [  "$key" == "" ]; then
      continue
    elif [[  "$key" =~ ^#.*$ ]]; then
      continue
    else
      echo $key " --> " $value
      keyValues[$key]=$value
    fi
  done < "$propertiesFilePath"

  if [ ! -f "$propertiesSecureFilePath" ]; then
    continue
  else
    while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
      if [  "$key" == "" ]; then
        continue
      elif [[  "$key" =~ ^#.*$ ]]; then
        continue
      else
        echo $key " --> " $value
        keyValues[$key]=$value
      fi
    done < "$propertiesSecureFilePath"
  fi

  for key in ${!keyValues[@]}; do
    envProp=${key//[@]/}
    if [  "$(eval echo '$'$envProp)" == "" ]; then
      echo "Environment key not exist" $envProp
    else
      value=$(eval echo '$'$envProp)
      echo "From Environment " $envProp " --> "$value 
      keyValues[$key]=$value
    fi
  done 


find "$filePathToAct" | while read -r resultFileName; do
  if [ ! -f "$resultFileName" ]; then
    continue
  else
    echo "Acting on the file $resultFileName"

    for key in ${!keyValues[@]}; do
      value=$(echo "${keyValues[${key}]}" | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
      echo "sed -i 's/$key/$value/g' $resultFileName "
      eval "sed -i 's/$key/$value/g' $resultFileName "
    done 
  fi
done 

}
```