# Using sed to update a property in a java properties file

Tags: java, sed

I'd like a simple one liner with `sed` to update a java property value. Without knowing what the current setting of the java property is, and it may be empty)

before

```
example.java.property=previoussetting
```

after

```
example.java.property=desiredsetting
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming Linux Gnu sed, 1 solution would be

**Edits** escaped '.' chars i.e. `s/example\.java.../` per correct comment by Kent

```
 replaceString=desiredsetting
 sed -i "s/\(example\.java\.property=\).*\$/\1${replaceString}/" java.properties
```

If you're using BSD `sed` on a Mac for instance, you'll need to supply an argument to the `-i` to indicate the backup filename. Fortunately, you can use

```
 sed -i '' "s/\(example\.java\.property=\).*\$/\1${replaceString}/" java.properties
```

as an argument, and avoid having to manage `.bak` files in your workflow. *(BSD `sed` info added 2018-08-10)*

If your sed doesn't honor the `-i`, then you have to manage tmp files, i.e.

```
    sed "s/\(example\.java\.property=\).*\$/\1${replaceString}/" java.properties > myTmp
    /bin/mv -f myTmp java.properties
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: -1 although OP has accepted this answer. the 'dot' is not escaped, so it means 'ANY character' it could change the wrong property in the file. it's dangerous!

Comment: @Kent : Dangerous seems like a strong term. But thanks for helping make my post better. Hoofamon : please see revised post for improve  replacements on your java properties. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 30):

This will update your file:

```
sed -i "/property.name=/ s/=.*/=newValue/" yourFile.properties
```

This will print into a new file

```
sed "/property.name=/ s/=.*/=newValue/" yourFile.properties > newFile.properties
```

This is how you update multiple properties

```
sed -i -e "/property.name.1=/ s/=.*/=newValue1/" -e "/property.name.2=/ s/=.*/=newValue2/" yourFile.properties
```

Gurus of **sed** may blame me since this is not the most proper way to do this (e.g. I didn't escape the dots) but I see this as the best option when you don't want to sacrifice readability.

Here's extended discussion:
[How do I use sed to change my configuration files, with flexible keys and values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955548/how-do-i-use-sed-to-change-my-configuration-files-with-flexible-keys-and-values)