# Linux command for file text replace

Tags: linux, string, shell, text, replace

I have file named 'server.cfg'. There is string 'port 7788', 7788 can be any number ( 7799, 7711 and so on ), i need to change that number which goes after port to 7777, how can i do that? I need ssh command, using debian. Thanks.

Comment: Try `man sed` and go through some examples. You'll find it pretty easy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use sed to change my configuration files, with flexible keys and values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955548/how-do-i-use-sed-to-change-my-configuration-files-with-flexible-keys-and-values)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`, like this:

```
sed -i 's/port \([0-9]*\)/port 7777/' server.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need sed.  If you want to change one specific instance use:

```
$ sed -i 's/port 7788/port 7777/g' server.cfg
```

If you want to change an unknown number multiple times use:

```
$ sed -i 's/port \([0-9]*\)/port 7777/' server.cfg
```

If you want to change only the first instance found, use:

```
$ sed -i '0,/port \([0-9]*\)/{s/port \([0-9]*\)/port 7777/}' server.cfg
```

Comment: ok, but as i have said, port XXXX, so i don't know what number is after port.

Comment: how can i know what number goes after port?

Comment: sed -i 's/port \([0-9]*\)/port 7777/' server.cfg

Answer (score 0):

You should use a regegex with sed :

```
sed -i 's/port [[:digit:]]\{4\}/port 7777/g' server.cfg
```

This will replace all the port number (with 4digits) by 7777

Comment: a port number can have 1 to 5 digits

Comment: You can do like this :

   sed -i 's/port [[:digit:]]\{1,5\}/port 7777/g' server.cfg