# How to replace a substring inside a file using shell script and match expression?

Tags: sh

I need to replace a specific string inside a CoffeeScript file. The file contains the following values inside:

```
  version                : '1.3.3.1204.0'
  buildVersion           : '1.3.3.1204.4'
```

Using shell script, I want to replace the values within quotes, nothing else. Notice there can be X amount of whitespaces between the name and the **:**

Desired output:

```
  version                : '2.0.0.0101.0'
  buildVersion           : '2.0.0.0101.1'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use sed to change my configuration files, with flexible keys and values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955548/how-do-i-use-sed-to-change-my-configuration-files-with-flexible-keys-and-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
$ sed "s@'1\.3\.3\.1204\.0'@'2.0.0.0101.0'@;\
       s@'1\.3\.3\.1204\.4'@'2.0.0.0101.1'@" file
```

### Output

```
  version                : '2.0.0.0101.0'
  buildVersion           : '2.0.0.0101.1'
```

### Note

Add `-i` switch if you want to replace *on the fly*