# Replace a value in a .py file with sed failing - BASH

Tags: bash, sed

I am working on a bash script to update passwords in a config file.

- The configuration file, `settings.py`, is a python file
- The password in the file is a variable, that looks like this:

`TEST_PASSWORD = 'SomeValue'`

What I need to do is enter in a command into the Linux terminal to scan into that file, and replace `'SomeValue'` with what I enter.

I imagine some pseudocode would look like:

```
update_password(){
    echo "What do you want to update the password to?"
    new_pass = -> Read in user value into

    -> update settings.py and change:
    TEST_PASSWORD = 'SomeValue'
    to
    TEST_PASSWORD = "'" + new_pass + "'"
}
```

(it must be enclosed as a string in the `settings.py` file)

So far, I have tried a one-liner:

`sed -i 's/TEST_PASSWORD = 'test'/TEST_PASSWORD = 'new_val'/g' test/settings.py`

and nothing happens. As in, the file doesn't change at all. [(referenced from here)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands)

The complete program looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a password: " password

echo "Got password"
echo " "

sed -i 's/TEST_PASSWORD = / TEST_PASSWORD = $password/g' test/settings.py
```

But in `settings.py`, it changes:

`TEST_PASSWORD = 'test'` to `TEST_PASSWORD = $password'test'`

How can I change the value of the `TEST_PASSWORD` in `settings.py` to the value that the user enters, without knowing what the current password is?

**For Reference:**
`awk -F= '/^NAME/{print $2}' /etc/os-release` yields: `"Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"`

Comment: `sed -i "s/TEST_PASSWORD = .*/TEST_PASSWORD = '$password'/g" test/settings.py`

Comment: You can't use single quotes inside single-quoted strings.

Comment: Should I ask @WiktorStribiżew to post this as an answer, or delete the question? I think this should be an answer. It worked.

Comment: IMHO, a duplicate of [How do I use sed to change my configuration files, with flexible keys and values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955548/how-do-i-use-sed-to-change-my-configuration-files-with-flexible-keys-and-values)

Comment: But also, don't store passwords in your Python scripts in the first place. Make them read a configuration file or environment variable instead of hard-coding a password, especially, one which then needs to be replaced using this very brittle approach.