# Change Document Root with command lines

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, command-line, stack

I'm setting up an Amazon Web Service Stack and I'd like to configure the Document Root in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf which I currently do by modifying the document's DocumentRoot. I then reflect this change in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf. Is it possible to make these changes with command lines as opposed to opening and editing files? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you have to use a command line editor to edit the file like "nano"

Comment: Use vim instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with sed. I use following wrapper function, to make it more convenient:

```
replace_string () {
    while :; do
        case $1 in
               file=?*) local    file=${1#*=} ;;
            replace=?*) local replace=${1#*=} ;;
               with=?*) local    with=${1#*=} ;;
                     *) break                 ;;
        esac
        shift
    done

    sudo sed -i -- "s/$replace/$with/ig" $file
}

replace_string    file='/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf' \
               replace='.*DocumentRoot.*' \
                  with='DocumentRoot path-to-your-document-root'


replace_string    file='/etc/apache2/apache2.conf' \
               replace='.*DocumentRoot.*' \
                  with='DocumentRoot "path-to-your-document-root"'
```

Mind that user running this script should be capable of using sudo without a password.

Comment: That's horrendous

Comment: @quant I hate bash and love ruby, so I've got a whole "framework" of such functions.

Answer (score 0):

## If you have httpd.conf file

I don't know if this is supported by the documentation or not (I couldn't see reference to it) but I found that appending will replace previous directives.

I stumbled upon this experimentally after becoming disillusioned with the cocophony of `sed`, `grep` and `awk` scripts that usually accompany this kind of question (see [Modify config file using bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464760/modify-config-file-using-bash-script)).

In my case, I have a file called `httpd_changes.conf` which looks like this:

```
DocumentRoot "/my/new/web/dir"
<Directory "/my/new/web/dir">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then when I set up the webserver (in my case it's in my `Dockerfile`) I run this prior to starting the `httpd` service:

```
cat httpd_changes.conf >> /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

## If you don't have a httpd.conf file

This isn't my situation but as far as I can tell you can just put a new config file in your `conf.d` directory. Those files are read in alphabetically (according to this page https://superuser.com/questions/705297/in-what-order-does-apache-load-conf-files-and-which-ones) which is obviously much nicer than my hack.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

`sed "s,/var/www/html,/my/new/web/dir,g" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

This will display the modification that would be made on your file.

The `,` is used as a custom delimiter to make the regex easier to read.
This example with replace all occurences of `/var/www/html` with `/my/new/web/dir`.

Add the `-i` flag to actually modify the file:

`sed -i "s,/var/www/html,/my/new/web/dir,g" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`