# modify a file using a bash script with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

similar to these questions:

- [modify config file using bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464760/modify-config-file-using-bash-script)
- [How do I use sed to change my configuration files, with flexible keys and values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955548/how-do-i-use-sed-to-change-my-configuration-files-with-flexible-keys-and-values/5955591#5955591)

In a file like this:

```
define('_DB_NAME_', 'anything');
define('_DB_USER_', 'something else');
define('_DB_PASSWD_', 'and another value');
```

how to use sed to replace the value `anything`, `something` and `another` (which are unknown) by refering to the key values `_DB_NAME_`, `_DB_USER_` and `_DB_PASSWD`?

Comment: Do you want to replace the second argument of the first line, or do you want to replace the `'anything'` argument wherever it appears?

Comment: I want to replace the value `anything` (which is unknown) depending on the key `_DB_NAME_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed "s/\(define('_DB_NAME_', \).*/\1'new value');/" filename
```

and likewise for the other two.

If you want to alter the file in place, you can use `-i`, but you have to be careful, different versions of sed handle that differently.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want:

```
sed -E "
  s/('_DB_NAME_', ')[^']+/\1ABC/
  s/('_DB_USER_', ')[^']+/\1DEF/
  s/('_DB_PASSWD_', ')[^']+/\1GHI/
"
```

I think awk is more readable:

```
awk -F "'" -v OFS="'" '
    $2 == "_DB_NAME_"   {$4 = "ABC"}
    $2 == "_DB_USER_"   {$4 = "DEF"}
    $2 == "_DB_PASSWD_" {$4 = "GHI"}
    {print}
'
```

Comment: the first one with sed says: `\1 not defined in the RE`

Comment: Try using `-r` instead of `-E` . What OS are you using?

Comment: now it's on macos, but eventually it will run on linux (I don't know exactly, it's a shared hosting running apache)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -e 's/anything/newanything/g;s/something/newthing/g;s/another/newanother/' tempfile
```

Where tempfile contains that code you had. Output looks like this

```
define('_DB_NAME_', 'newanything');
define('_DB_USER_', 'newthing else');
define('_DB_PASSWD_', 'and newanother value');
```

Comment: I edited my question for clarity. The value `anything` is unknown. So the goal is to replace it by referring to `_DB_NAME_`

Comment: @francoisromain ah i see sorry I jumped the gun a little there